# Is a one sample t test the right approach for this question?

Tags: self-study, t-test

This is an example from my book that I'm trying to figure out but I'm totally lost. Can someone complete this step by step so I understand?

> A new meditation technique based on making barnyard animal noises promises to calm people, but you might be skeptical. You can imagine that it could cause stress to sit around oinking and mooing. To test the therapy, you ask 16 people to make animal noises, then ask them to rate emotion on a scale from 1-7, with 1 representing “Very Calm,” and 7 representing “Very Stressed.” You happen to know that people who don’t oink and moo have an average emotion rating of 4, with a standard deviation of 2.57. Below are the ratings from the 16 people who made animal noises.

```
 4  5   6   5   4   3   7   4   

 3  4   4   3   5   6   5   4
```

> Write the null and alternative hypotheses for this example.
>   Write the specific type of analysis you will use.
>   Zobt? Z crit?
>   Provide a statement of a significant or nonsignificant effect.
>   Write the obtained value.

I believe my null and alternate hypotheses are:

$\text{H}_0: \overline{X}= μ\quad\text{vs}\quad    \text{H}_1:\overline{X} \neq μ$

for $t$ I did  $\frac{4.5-4}{2.57/\sqrt{16}}$ and got $.778$? Is this correct?

My $z_\text{crit}$ would be $2.131$?

Comment: Welcome to the list. The first two things you should do are 1) Choose a better title for your question and 2) Add the "self-study" tag.

Comment: I have done so.

Comment: In addition, post the things you have tried. You are unlikely to get a response just posting a bald textbook question without demonstrating what the effort you've made.

Comment: I have added the effort I have made, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Please also read the `self-study` [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). If you do seek someone to complete the question step by step as your question asks, you're likely to be disappointed. Self-study questions are answered with the aim to get you to complete the question yourself. If hints and guidance are not sufficient, you may need a different form of help that we can offer here.

Answer (score 3):

Let's begin with the requisite hints and guidance.

A number of things you have there are wrong. Let's look at a few:

1. You're given several pointers to this not being a t-test (the fact that you're given a known standard deviation and the repeated reference to $z$).
2. Hypotheses don't involve sample quantities (like $\overline{x}$), but population quantities. It's about a comparison of the (unknown) population mean rating of people making animal noises (for which you have a sample) against the known population mean rating of people not making animal noises.
3. your critical value should not be from t-tables
4. you haven't stated a significance level. Since none is given in the question, this should be one of the early things to do, and certainly before you calculate a test statistic.
5. you should explicitly state the assumption you made about $\sigma$ for the animal noise group (that it's the same as the population s.d for the no-noise group). If you don't make that assumption (and it isn't going to be easy to justify - the question offers no justification, as Nick points out below), you would use the one-sample t-test, but in that case your calculation of the test statistic would change)

One the plus side:

1. you're right that it's one-sample.
2. I believe your calculation of the test statistic is correct for the z-test; you found all the necessary pieces of information. However the fact that you didn't compute a sample standard deviation while doing so should have been a big clue that it wasn't a t-test.

Comment: I think the question is written misleadingly; I don't understand why a $Z_{\rm critical}$ is requested. A *z*-test is inappropriate without knowledge of the experimental population's standard deviation. It doesn't seem justified to assume the given $\sigma$ parameter for the control population would apply equally to the test population.

Comment: @Nick +1 while no justification is offered that the two population sds should be the same, I believe that's the required assumption, as the request for $Z_\text{crit}$ and $Z_\text{obt}$ information makes clear. This assumption is no more odd than the (very) common use of equal-variance two-sample t-tests which make the same assumption with no more justification offered than is given here. However, you did remind me of something I intended to put in my answer - the need to make that rather significant assumption explicit.

Comment: So would my hypothesis be Ho:4.5=μ and H1: 4.5≠μ? Also I used .05.

Comment: Yes, I know you used $\alpha=0.05$ (I could tell from the critical value you stated), but you didn't say so. Replacing the symbol $\bar x$ with the actual numeric value in your hypothesis doesn't solve the problem I stated 0 you're still inserting sample quantities into something that should contain *population* information. Include only population values in your hypothesis (and explicitly state what your symbols mean - what's $\mu$ the population mean of?)

Comment: o_o So...4=μ and H1: 4≠μ of average emotion rating?

Comment: ***Which*** average emotion rating is $\mu$? It's more conventional to write a parameter to the left and a numeric value to the right, btw.

Comment: The whole population I think.

Comment: The "4" is the value for the mean population emotion score for the non-animal-noise group. Think about what the question of interest was; what do you want to compare with that mean?

Comment: The mean of the animal noise group? Ho.4=4.5 and H1: 4≠4.5

Comment: Is 4 = 4.5? You don't need data for that, it's obviously false. Also, 4.5 is a *SAMPLE* value, and as we already established, that has no place in a hypothesis. Go back to the $\mu$, just *define it properly*. AGAIN, what is the original question of interest, (*in words*)? Think *very* carefully before you write anything. It's important to understand this issue clearly.

Comment: :c I don't think I'm picking up on what you're attempting to explain. Can you just say what you're trying to get me to figure out then explain it? Also am I correct in my assumption that this z test is two tailed?

Comment: I can't tell whether the intent is for it to be one or two-tailed. The question, as ambiguous as it is, is hardly clear. There's at least a suggestion of a one-tailed hypothesis, but which way to go on that little bit of evidence would partly depend on how you've been taught as well as the conventions for your area (I am no experimental psychologist, though I've worked with a few - I rely on them to know their own conventions). I gave detailed information about what you need to do with the hypotheses. Your comment that started "o_o" could be right *if you correctly establish what $\mu$ is*.

Comment: So...Ho: 4= average emotion rating of people who dont make animal sounds? H1: 4≠ average emotion rating of people who dont make animal sounds? You mean written out like this?

Comment: :/ This is all very confusing to me.

Comment: 1) I don't know how I can be more explicit. LEAVE $\mu$ IN THE HYPOTHESIS, BUT DEFINE IT. 2) Given that "4" is explicitly given as "the average emotion rating of people who dont make animal sounds", that would be utterly pointless to test. YOU KNOW IT IS TRUE. 3) *LEAVING ASIDE* the statement of the hypothesis for the present FIRST think about what it is you're trying to achieve here. Express *THAT* in words, without any jargon. That will guide you in defining $\mu$.

Comment: :( I'm trying to achieve finding if the meditation has any significant effect?

Comment: ... effect on what? What is it you're comparing with what? (and 'significant' is not a scientific issue but a statistical one - it's not the underlying question)

Comment: I'm comparing the average emotion rating of those that made animals sounds with the population that doesn't

Comment: But the question of interest isn't about the *sample* value of "average emotion rating of those that made animals" (because that will - always, and unimportantly - differ). Can you write that again, but write it in terms of something a researcher might care to actually know? You're almost right.

Comment: I'm comparing the effect of animal noise meditation on stress levels compared to the stress levels of those who didn't do animal noise meditation?

Comment: Yes, but more specifically, the researcher wants to know about the comparison between *population* means of those two things (inference about population quantities, as I mentioned before, is what hypotheses are about). One of the two population means is known (it's $4$). What population mean is that 4? What is that particular population mean being compared with in your comment just now? Can you state what $\mu$ is in $\text{H}_0: \mu=4$ now?

Comment: people who don’t oink and moo.

Comment: 1) NO. Please re-read the entire thread ***carefully***. What's the question of interest again? What two potentially different things are being compared in that question of interest? One of those things turns out to have the value $4$, but what's the ***OTHER*** thing? 2) I'm pretty sure you don't think $\mu$ is a class of people. Say what you actually mean.

Comment: Q.Q This is just an intro class...I feel like you're over complicating it.

Comment: It's actually *very* simple, but I am focusing on trying to get you to think about and understand what you're actually doing (which will lead to understanding) than giving the answer (which I am enjoined from doing by the `self-study` guidelines). Please do try to think about the point. You've ALREADY been told that the population mean emotion score for "people who don't oink and moo" is 4. YOU KNOW THIS. There's no point in testing that. Why would you suggest that we should test $\mu=4$ where "$\mu$ is the population mean emotion score for "people who don't oink and moo" when it *IS* 4?...ctd

Comment: ctd... and why on earth would we measure the sample mean of people who *do* oink and moo if BOTH sides of our hypothesis were about people who don't? Here's an alternative suggestion: write your hypotheses containing $\mu_{\text{animal-noises}}$ and $\mu_{\text{no-noises}}$ based on the question of interest discussed above (on a piece of paper, say). Once you've done that, *replace the one you know is 4 with the value 4*. What do you end up with?

Comment: Understanding how to think about populations and formulate your hypotheses in terms of them is about the most fundamental concept you need for understanding tests based on random sampling of populations (such as the t- z- and chi-squared test rely on) - more fundamental than significance levels, normal distributions, even than being able to calculate standard deviations. You need to understand how to write a question of interest in terms of population quantities and how to turn it into a null and alternative hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Your hypotheses look good to me, but, "You can imagine that it could cause stress to sit around oinking and mooing," sounds like a directional hypothesis, so a one-sided hypothesis is also worth considering. Then again, one-sided hypothesis tests seem to be rather controversial, so maybe not!

Your calculation of *t* is incorrect. You're right that $\bar X=4.5, \mu=4$ and $N=16$, but the population standard deviation in the question is sort of a red herring. You need to use the sample standard deviation for a one-sample *t*-test.

I don't understand why a $Z_{\rm critical}$ is requested. A *Z*-test is inappropriate without knowledge of the experimental population's standard deviation. It doesn't seem justified to assume the given *SD* parameter for the control population would apply equally to the test population. For one thing, without controlling for personality differences like extraversion or self-monitoring, making animal noises might increase variability in stress levels by allowing some people to release stress by acting silly while making others more stressed due to embarrassment. By the way, the question implies that the ordinal data from the Likert scale for stress assessment can be treated as continuous, which is also fishy...

Furthermore, even if a $t_{\rm critical}$ was requested instead, the appropriate value to provide would depend on the choice of false positive error rate $\alpha$ for the test. It's conventional to choose $\alpha=.05$, so if you haven't been given any other reason to choose a different error rate, you probably won't go wrong (for grading purposes at least) with $t_{(\alpha=.95,df=15)}=2.131$ as long as you don't call it a $Z_{\rm critical}$.

You don't seem to have attempted the last part, "Provide a statement of a significant or nonsignificant effect." Give it a shot. It shouldn't be too hard as long as you choose your words carefully (don't get too creative, and be careful not to claim more than your results actually tell you) and understand which conclusion is appropriate when your test statistic is higher vs. lower than the critical value.

Comment: " you need to use the sample standard deviation for a one-sample t-test" <---I thought it was a z test though? It also asks me to Sketch the z-distribution, and include a p-value for the rejection region(s) as well  as zcrit value(s). You guys have a link to a site that will sketch it for me?

Comment: Read the next paragraph.

Comment: Also see Nick's comment under my answer as explanation for why he thinks it shouldn't be a z-test. From a practical statistical point of view his reasoning is quite sound (if this was a real problem, I'd probably use a $t$ as well - or to be honest, perhaps a permutation test), though I am pretty sure the intent in the question is that you use a $Z$; I agree with Nick that the question is misleading - that's the case no matter which way you look at it. It can be tricky to guess what people want when they ask questions that don't make required assumptions clear - but you must make them clear.

Comment: But really, read the next paragraph. I elaborated on the comment! It's right there after the line you quoted...

Comment: +1 for the answer - while we don't agree about the intent of the question (which is less than clear, so that's not surprising), I can't say I disagree with anything else, and you raise important issues. This answer is worthwhile for any beginner trying to come to grips with the issues and reasoning.

Comment: Actually, I agree with you about the intent of the question @Glen_b. Maybe I should add that my answer may take a little arguing to support, or lean somewhat heavily on the openmindedness of whoever's grading the answers, because the intent of the question is wrong! This makes the truly right answer trickier than it would otherwise be. It might still be marked incorrect, but it is more defensible than the implicitly "correct" answer, which would use a *Z*-test...